# How to find the index of last element which is non-zero in array

Tags: matlab

I have a vector `d` that its size `1x1000`. It stores a random values from `0` to `1`. For example

```
d=[0.0076 0.4629 0.1554...0 0 0 0 ...0.0442 0 0 0 10^-7 10^-7 10^-7]
```

Now, I want to get the index of element at the last of vector (has maximize index) subject to `non-zero` or bigger than `10^-7`). For my example, the element that has value is **0.0442** and `index=`?. How to implement it by MATLAB? Thank all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find the last element that satisfies a condition, you can use the syntax `find(tf, 1, 'last')`.

In your case, you want to find the last value that is more than a certain tolerance away from zero, i.e.

```
tol = 2e-7;
idx = find( abs(d)>tol, 1, 'last');
```

Note: I've used `abs(d)` so that the solution is robust to negative values in the input, and I set the tolerance to `2e-7` to increase the likelihood that the threshold is in between the most likely good values and the most likely bad values (setting it to 1e-6 may be even safer).

Comment: I think it must be idx = find( abs(d)>tol, 1, 'last');

Comment: @user3051460: oops, that's a pretty fatal typo!

Comment: Why would you use ``abs(d)`` instead of ``d``? I think it was not asked for absolute values.

Comment: Also why would you set the tolerance to ``2e-7`` instead of the required ``1e-7``. Of course those are no big deals, as suggested method clearly is correct, but it seems unnecessary to change those values.

Comment: @Nras: I use `abs`, since even though the OP's post had only positive values, my solution works for negative non-nearly-zero values as well. I set the tolerance to 2e-7, since the 1e-7 in the vector could well be a 1.000000000001e-7, which means that it would not get filtered. You are right in that I should have explained my decisions.

Answer (score 3):

```
 ind = find(d ~= 0);
 ind(end) = % last nonzero index
 d(ind(end)) = % last nonzero element
```

You can add threshold: `ind = find(d > 1e-7)`

If you also have negative data you may add threshold like `ind = find(d > 1e-7 | d < -1e-7)`

Comment: How about if I want to ignore 10^-7 (very small value)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `max` and `cumsum` -

```
tol = 1e-7; %// tolerance value
[~,index] = max(cumsum(d>tol))
```